# sublime linter stopped working for lesshint when .lesshintrc file added in project root directory

Tags: less, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I have installed lesshint via npm

`npm install lesshint -g`

installed sublimeLinter and than [sublimeLinter-contrib-lesshint](https://github.com/jasjuang/SublimeLinter-contrib-lesshint) package and the linter is enabled.

now whenever I open any *.less* file in sublime, linter gives all kind of warning such as *SpaceAfterPropertyColon* , *SingleQuots* , *ZeroWidth* and much more which is the default behavior.

Now I tried to configure the linter according to my need in the project, so added the *.lesshintrc* file in project root directory and restart the sublime text 3.

BUT now everything stopped working, no linting error coming up. even I tried to set error explicitly in the .less file. There is no error in the sublime console too.

on other hand, inline linting configuration works fine by putting rules the on top in any file such as

//lesshint-disable importantRule, propertyOrdering, emptyRule

What could be the issue?

Below is the system detail and *.lesshintrc* file content.

- macOS 10.13.1
- sublime text 3 build 3143
- node v 8.9.2

#### .lesshintrc

```
{
 "fileExtensions": [".less", ".css"],

"excludedFiles": ["vendor.less"],

"spaceAfterPropertyColon": {
    "enabled": true,
    "style": "one_space"
},
"singleLinePerSelector": false,
"propertyOrdering": false,
"importantRule": false 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lead maintainer of `lesshint` here.

This was caused by an regression in `lesshint`, but is fixed in `lesshint@4.6.3`.

Run `npm install -g lesshint` again and things should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked. btw I have fixed by removing the `"excludedFiles": ["vendor.less"]`. from *.lesshintrc*